# Binary tree creation from file without recursions C++

Tags: c++, binary-tree

For starters, I would like to apologize because I didn't know how to word the title appropriately. Here is the issue that I have.
I'm having an issue while creating a tree from a file.
The file looks like this:

```
0 1 3 4
0 1 4
0 2 3 3 4
0 2 3 4
```

And the tree that I need to create should look like this:

```
        0
      /   \
     1     2
    / \    |
   3   4   3
   |      / \
   4     3   4
         |
         4
```

Using words to explain, in each row of the file I am given a new stack of data, and I should create a tree but if the sequence exists, I should follow it until there is a break in it.

While creating the tree, I used this method to check if there are sequences that already exist:

```
void Tree::addNewStack(const string& line) {
istringstream stack(line);
string token;

Node* currentNode = nullptr;

while (stack >> token) {
    Node* newNode = new Node(token);

    if (root == nullptr) {
        root = newNode;
    }
    else {
        // Checking for existing node.
        Node* existingNode = nullptr;
        currentNode = root;

        while (existingNode == nullptr && currentNode != nullptr) {
            if (currentNode->left != nullptr && current->left->data == token) {
                existingNode = currentNode->left;
            }
            else if (currentNode->right != nullptr && current->right->data == token) {
                existingNode = currentNode->right;
            }
            // ****
        }
        // If there is an existingNode move to it, otherwise make a new node.
        if (existingNode != nullptr) {
            currentNode = existingNode;
            currentNode = newNode;
        }
    else {
                currentNode = newNode;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried making a priority queue and then making a tree using a preorder traversal, but that seemed more complicated.

Inside the while loop where the comment with stars is, I can't figure out how to search through the whole loop. I need to find a way to update the currentNode so that I traverse through the whole tree. I tried with currentNode = currentNode->left, but that only checks one side of the tree. Also tried making 2 while loops, one to check the left and one to check the right side but that also didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Edited it, sorry.

Comment: IDK if you have control over the format of that input file, but as it currently reads you may not be able to make some of the assumptions currently being made. For example, what if you get as input `0 1 2`, `5 6 7`? As-is, traversing the tree for each input line is unavoidable.

Comment: That should be an error that @Atmo provided the solution for.

Comment: What you are building looks something like a trie, rather than the conventional tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only **1** root in your tree.
The token corresponding to the root is indeed repeated several times in the file (once for each line) but judging from the parameter being named `const string& line`, the method will only have to treat it **once** for each call. It is not mentioned in your question but I have to assume in my answer that another method builds the `line` strings out of the file in a loop and pass them to `Tree::addNewStack` one by one.

Since `currentNode` needs to be initialized only once within each call, you should process the root **before** the `while` loop instead of inside it (it should make sense we do the initialization before entering the loop).

The rest should flow easily for a binary tree (not a binary **search** tree) as per your question; we will fill `left` before `right` at every level:

```cpp
stack >> token;
if (!root)
    root = new Node(token);
else if (root->data != token)
    throw "The root specified in file does not match the root of the tree";
Node* currentNode = root;

while (stack >> token) {
    if (!currentNode->left)
        currentNode = currentNode->left = new Node(token);
    else if (currentNode->left->data == token)
        currentNode = currentNode->left;
    else if (!currentNode->right)
        currentNode = currentNode->right = new Node(token);
    else if (currentNode->right->data == token)
        currentNode = currentNode->right;
    else
        throw "Path is incompatible with tree";
}
```

---

If you want to generate a binary search tree, you need to add 1 layer of logic to treat:

- `if (token <= currentNode->data)` -> Check only the left branch.
- `else` -> Check only the right branch.

Again, the tree in your question is not a BST as the 2 nodes under `1` are bigger than `1` so your file should raise an exception on token `4` of the 2nd line of the file (for node `1`, `currentNode->right` is alreay occupied by `3`).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try this method and I will update you. Also, I don't need BST but thank you for clarification. I will practice BST later and this will help.

Comment: Update: I also managed to do something like this earlier. The problem is that now every node has only 1 child node, the left one, and the whole tree is "linear": 0 - 1 - 3 - 4 - 0 - 1 - 4 - 0 - 2 - ...

Comment: I suppose what you are describing would occur if you processed the whole file inside the `Tree::addNewStack(const string& line)` method. You named the parameter **`line`** though, so my code expects you to break the file down outside of the method, then call it once for each line read (inside a `try ... catch ...` since exceptions may be raised). You surely can confirm that by checking the content or size/length of `line` at the start of the function with your debugger. Let me know what you get.

Comment: You are correct, I'm indeed processing the whole file inside the `addNewStack` function since I'm supposed to load the tree from the file on start, but I should be able to add new parts of the tree from the console input as well, sorry that my variable naming confused you.

Comment: Then you need to break it down into 2 methods, like I said. The first method does `while (std::getline(file, line)) try addNewStack(line), catch (...) {...}` (The `try ... catch ...` is optional, maybe you want the exception to be propagated upward, i.e. not caught here).